# Рассчитать размер прямоугольника с текстом

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

В делегате `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat` я должен высчитать высоту моего текста в UILabel. Какими путями мне это сделать, скажите, пожалуйста?

upd1(к первому комментарию) :

```
    let text = self.posts[indexPath.row]["story"]! as NSString
    let sizeOfLabel = text.boundingRectWithSize(
        CGSize(width: <<MY_WIDTH>>, height: Int.min),
        options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
        attributes: ["NSFontAttributeName":UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)],
        context: nil)
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у Вас проблема с размером `UILabel` в `UITableView`. При создании вашей `UILabel` в методе `UITableViewDataSource` нужно указать `yourLabel.layoutIfNeeded()`. Если это не то, опишите проблему точнее

Comment: Не знаю - то или не то, ибо объектов ```UILabel``` несколько, а также присутствуют ```UIImage```. А также много определено constraints. И теперь пытаюсь рассчитывать динамически высоту cell.

Comment: @drewpts Тогда это то, что Вам нужно. Я так понимаю Вы подгружаете данные из какой-то модели, то есть при создании каждой ячейки Вы в ней указываете необходимые данные. `layoutIfNeeded()` сделает всю работу за Вас. Он автоматический рассчитает нужный размер. Так же если у Вас `UILabel`, то стоит внутри его настроек установить количество строк = 0. Надеюсь помог!

Comment: Я попробую, спасибо!
А еще, простите за оффтоп: а Вы не подскажете как использовать в swift именованные блоки? По типу как в c++ именованную лямбду:
```auto fnobj = []() { return 5; }; auto x = 5*fnobj();```

а то у меня получалось только блоки возвращающие Void именовать. Но как использовать блоки возвращающие нечто другое и использовать их в выражениях - как в примере выше?

Comment: @drewpts нет, не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UILabel {
    func calculateHeight() -> Float {
        let text = self.text as NSString
        let size = text.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: self.font])
        return size.height
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Мне нужно заполнить текст, когда я знаю ширину. Этим способом скорее всего не получишь требуемое. Как насчет моего решения (см upd1)?

Answer (score 1):

То, что у вас в апдейте должно работать, единственно`height` не минимальный а максимальный

```
let sizeOfLabel = text.boundingRectWithSize(
    CGSize(width: <<MY_WIDTH>>, height: DBL_MAX),
    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
    attributes: ["NSFontAttributeName":UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)],
    context: nil)
```

Comment: А, да. Спасибо!